# Pre-populating new Page creation with shortcodes

Tags: pages, shortcode

I would like to have my authors to be able to create new pages on my site, but I would like a couple of shortcodes to automatically be included when they create each page. The shortcodes independently work with pages already with no adjustments or editing. How can I have this done automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can add any default content you like, but I don't know of a way of doing it *just* for Pages (the following will apply to both Pages *and* Posts):

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_default_post_content' );

function my_default_post_content( $content ) {
    $content = "Hello World!";
    return $content;
}
```

(place this in your `functions.php` file)